# How to disable link previews and link dropdowns

Tags: mail.app, email, graphics, url, ventura

Since updating to Ventura, whenever I paste or type a URL into an email draft, Mail app now automatically crowds my message with large content previews, it pings websites and downloads images to add as attachments to my email drafts, and it displays distracting dropdown carets next to every existing URL.

Is there any way to disable any or all of these unwanted new features, either by GUI pref or Terminal command? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Ventura pasted links in Mail appear to have following behavior:

- pasted link is "Link Preview" if e-mail body is empty or link is not pasted after and next to any text
- pasted link is "Plain link" if it's pasted immediately after any text/character in e-mail body (one character is sufficient)

Dropdown caret pop-up window enables switching from one link type to another and opening link (as clicking on link itself does nothing). For the latter functionality I am skeptical about possibility to remove it.

Workaround is to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and paste link into pop-up window (or paste link between () or convert existing text into link). Dropdown caret will still be there.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the email compositions to plain text prevents this feature from being applied:

`Mail > Settings > Composing > Message format: Plain Text`

Comment: That would strip all hyperlinks, bold/italic/underline/strikethroughs, bullets, etc.

Comment: Yes, it would avoid for all unnecessary stuff to make its way into the email ;)