# mail app now converts a link to a picture. How do I return to pasting a link?

Tags: links

How do I get Mail to go back to pasting links into mail instead of converting them to oversize buttons?

Comment: Similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450548/how-to-disable-link-previews-and-link-dropdowns but no answer yet

Comment: I can't test, but have you tried Cmd/Opt/Shift/V [the old Paste & Match Style command] ?

Comment: Unfortunately Paste & Match Style command doesn't prevent converting it into 'Preview link'. However any text before pasted link enforces 'Plain link'.